# Generating any # of random math questions based on user input in Javascript using LOOPS

Tags: javascript

My task is to create a program in Javascript that generates however many math questions the user wants based on their answer through a prompt. So if the user were to answer the prompt saying they want 5 questions, I would need 5 math questions generated, all with random numbers that change every time the page is refreshed. (questions can be very simple math problems)

The program also needs to ask the user for the answers to the questions, and display their answer AND the correct answer to the questions on the webpage afterwards. Loops also need to be involved in the code for this exercise.

I am a beginners level web programming student, and I am not too sure where to start to code this, because my teacher has not given us many examples and practice for using loops to make this programs. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Ivy, we are not code generators. Please do your own work, try something and when you have an error come back here with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Javascript? No other langaue possible? Javascript won't be the easiest language for a beginner...

But if you have to use it:
- Generate a HTML Unput field where User can enter a Number of how many math questions he want

- Evaluate the number and run a loop, wich generates the numbers of question.
- Use a Random Method for generating numbers. 
  Take look at this: https://gist.github.com/kerimdzhanov/7529623
- Display the questions with a html input field for the answer of the user
- Solve the question with javascript
- Compare the answer of the user with your result
- Display if true or false, display your calculated result for showing the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I must use Javascript. However, I'm not sure how to code the loop so it will create the amount of questions that the user wants?

Comment: Okay, thats not a problem. For example, you can use a for loop. Initialise it with the user input.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp
Look at this example. The for loop will be executed, until i reach the value cars.lengts -1, because there is a < in the statement. (The < > in for loops are handled like in math).
So you should do something like this:
for(i = 0; i < Number_Of_Userinput; i++)